# Infinite series solution of integral

Tags: definite-integrals, power-series

The following integral appears in Niels Bohr's paper "On the theory of the decrease of velocity of moving electrified particles on passing through matter" (https://doi.org/10.1080/14786440108634305)

\begin{equation} 
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos xz}{(z^{2}+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}} dz
\end{equation}

In this paper, Bohr provides a convergent series solution to the integral involving Euler's constant $\gamma$=0.5772 for all $x$ and an asymptotic series solution when $x$ is large.

Following integral also appears in subsequent discussion:

\begin{equation} 
Q_{2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{e^{2}}{m} E^{2} V^{2} \left[\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z \sin nz}{(V^{2}z^{2}+p^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} dz\right]^{2} \cdots + 
\end{equation}

Can anybody suggest how to solve such integrals and how are the solutions arrived at?

#### Added after @Goncalo comment

Solution provided by Bohr is given by (for all $x$)

\begin{equation}
f(x) = 1- \frac{1}{1.1.2}\frac{3}{1.2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{4} - \frac{1}{1.2.1.2.3}\left(\frac{3}{1.2} +\frac{5}{2.3}\right)\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{6} \cdots - \frac{1}{(n-1)! n!}\left( \frac{3}{1.2} +\frac{5}{2.3} + \cdots \frac{2n-1}{(n-1)n} \right)\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n} + \cdots \left(2\gamma + 2 \log \frac{x}{2} -1 \right) \left( \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2} + \frac{1}{1.1.2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{4} + \frac{1}{1.2.1.2.3}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{6} \cdots + \frac{1}{(n-1)! n!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n}\cdots \right) 
\end{equation}

Solution to the second is given as

\begin{equation} 
Q_{2} = \frac{2e^{2}E^{2}}{mV^{2}p^{2}}g^{2}\left(\frac{np}{V}\right)
\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation} 
g(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z \sin xz}{(z^{2}+1)^{2}}dz = \frac{x}{2}\int\limits_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos xz}{(z^{2}+1)^{2}}dz =  f^{\prime}(x)
\end{equation}

#### Note after comment by @Gary

I would appreciate if somwbody can give a detailed solution to the integrals as the steps in Bohr's paper are not available and probably were included due to brevity.

Comment: The article gives also another term proportional to $(2\gamma+2\log\frac x2-1)$.

Comment: Is $n=x$ in your second $f(x)$?

Comment: @Gary: Question is modified and provided with additional details. Would be grateful if a detailed solution can be provided.

Answer (score 2):

For the second integral, assuming that $(x,V,p)$ are positive, Mathematica returns

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{z \sin (xz)}{(V^{2}z^{2}+p^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}} dz=\frac{2 }{V^3}xK_0\left(\frac{ p}{V}x\right)$$ which makes
$$f(x)=\frac{2 e^2 E^2 x^2 }{m V^4}\left(K_0\left(\frac{p }{V}x\right){}\right)^2$$

$$t=\frac{p }{V}x \quad \implies \quad f(t)=\frac{2 e^2 E^2 }{m p^2 V^2}\ \, \left(t\,K_0(t) \right)^2$$

Expanded as series around $t=0$ appear more complex coefficients (just as mentioned @user for the first integral). Have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Series%5Bt%5E2+BesselK%5B0%2C+t%5D%5E2%2C+%7Bt%2C+0%2C+17%7D%5D+).

For large values of $t$
$$\left(t\,K_0(t) \right)^2=\frac \pi 2 \,t\, e^{-2t}\left( 1-\frac{1}{4 t}+\frac{5}{32 t^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^3}\right)\right)$$ is a quite good approximation as soon as $t>3$.